# Unable to find bundled Java version before using flutter

Tags: flutter, installation

[this was the error at first and hot help you all out these are the steps which I did to solve this

- go to your program files
- android and delete the empty android folder which is the previous version and you are good to go][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGWbw.png)

Answer (score 0):

[solved by deleting the old version folder which contains nothing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqE7m.png)

Comment: SDK is downloading ;)